# Влияние выбора целевой платформы компиляции на режим выполнения управляемого приложения в Windows

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Если я в Visual Studio укажу в качестве целевой платформы компиляции ARM или Itanium, какой формат будет иметь полученный исполняемый файл: PE32 или PE32+?

Так же интересует такой вопрос: При указании целевой платформы как `anycpu32bit-preferred`, в каком режиме (как x64 приложение, как x86 приложение, WOW64) будет выполняться полученный исполняемый файл на Windows RT (ARM) и на Windows IA64.

[Аналогичный вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51693732/1548895).

Answer (score 1):

Удалось найти вот такую таблицу с влиянием платформы на модуль.[image: таблицу]
[Ссылка](http://storage.piter.com/upload/contents/978549600433/978549600433_p.pdf) на источник, там есть информация поподробнее.

Comment: Это таблица из книжки Рихтера CLR via C#. На её основе и возникают вопросы. Почему это при компиляции со значением параметра `ARM` тип выходного модуля PE32+/Itanium?

Comment: В более ранней редакции, для .NET 2.0, указывается что при компиляции со значением параметра `Itanium` получается тот же тип выходного модуля: PE32+/Itanium. Про `ARM` там ничего, логично, не сказано (ведь Windows RT ещё не появилась)...

Comment: Думаю, тут надо копать в сторону ILAsm, выполняющего сборку.

Comment: @D.Stark Видимо, здесь никто не смог вам помочь. Переведите вопрос на английский (внесите эти замечания про Рихтера и картинку) и добавьте сюда ссылку. Если и там не ответят довольно быстро, я могу назначить там конкурс.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693732/the-effect-of-selecting-the-target-compilation-platform-on-the-execution-mode-of

Comment: @D.Stark Вам HansPassant ответил в комментарие, считаю это классным успехом! А как вы думаете?

Comment: Местный эксперт?